# Evaluate $h(z)=\frac {k}{2\pi} \int_CF(\theta)e^{ikz\cos \theta}\,d\theta$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Suppose this integral
$$h(z)=\frac {k}{2\pi} \int_CF(\theta)e^{ikz\cos \theta}\,d\theta$$
$$0\le\theta\le\pi$$
$$|z|\le l$$
We are in complex $\theta$ plane.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qziJ.png]

Assume we have knowledge of $F(\theta)$

The questions are,

1. Is it possible to find the value of $h$ at specific points?
2. Is it possible to approximate $h$ via this integral? Or simply approximate this integral according to given information?
3. Does differentiation under integral sign lead us anywhere?!

Any ambiguity in the question, please let me know!

Comment: Well on two parts of this contour, $d\theta \equiv 0$; on the other, we can see that $f$ being continuous is sufficient; I believe absolute continuity is both necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @ChrisK What about $h$?

Comment: Depending on how $F$ behaves (that is if it is continuous), you can evalute $h$. Just making sure, but in the context of your problem, the "x-axis" is the $\theta$ coordinate and the "y-axis" is the $r$ coordinate, right?

Comment: @ChrisK Yeah, suppose I know $F$ is continuous and I know its formula, is there anyway to approximate $h$? if not, is there any way to find some specific values of $h$ to write approximation for? I just need some values of $h$, even in expression form, not numerical one